# php dynamicly populating the drop down list based on the selected value of first list

Tags: php, html, mysql

Before I start I am aware that mysql is depreciated but my supervisor wants me to use it for this project.

Currently I have two drop downs. One drop down is hard-coded in my code and the other drop down is pulled from my database "users_db".

The hard-coded drop down contains the values: "Primary School", "Junior Cycle", "Senior Cycle".

The table labelled "school" contains the column "name_school". The table is populated as follows:

The name_school are "Goldsmith Hall", "Marian College", "Ringsend", "St.Andrew's"

When user selects "Primary School" from the first drop down I want the second drop down to populate with only "Goldsmith Hall" and "Marian College". And when the user selects "Junior Cycle" or "Senior Cycle" I want the second drop down to populate with only "Ringsend" and "St.Andrew's".

I know that I will probably need an AJAX onchange or javascript? But my problem is that I have gone through tutorials without much luck

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me

```
  <label for="year_of_study">Year of study</label>
  <select name="study_year" id="study_year">
  <option value="null" selected>--Select One--</option>
  <option value="Leaving Certificate">Senior Cycle</option>
  <option value="Junior Certificate">Junior Cycle</option>
  <option value="Primary School">Primary School</option>
</select>

<br>

  <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("users_db");
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name_school FROM school";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  ?>


<label for="student_availability">Availability</label>
  <select name="student_availability" id="student_availability">
  <option value="null" selected>--Select One--</option>

  <?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {      

  echo "<option value=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($row['name_school'])."\">".$row["name_school"]."</option>";

  }
  ?>

   </select>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried with the AJAX method, it's indeed a good way to deal with your problem. A simple way to implement it would be calling [ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) from jQuery

Comment: that's the problem, I don't even know where to start with the ajax method. There's just web pages recommending an ajax method but no tutorials or help.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials to learn it, you can [try this one](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). 

This one is for AJAX in general, so you can understand how it work before using jQuery's method.